# Only fail to connect to camera service , execute uncaughtException on android

Tags: android, android-camera

Now, I try this.

MainActivity.java

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtException(MainActivity.this));
```

UncaughtException.class

```
public class UncaughtException implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
private Context context;
private static Context context1;

public UncaughtException(Context ctx) {
    context = ctx;
    context1 = ctx;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e){
    try {
        StringBuilder report =new StringBuilder();
        sendErrorMail(report);
    } catch (Throwable ignore) {
        Log.e(UncaughtException.class.getName(),
                "Error while sending error e-mail", ignore);
    }
}

public void sendErrorMail(final StringBuilder errorContent) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            builder.setTitle("sorry.");
            builder.create();
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    });
            builder.setMessage("OoOopps, Your application has crashed");
            builder.show();
            Looper.loop();
                        }
        }.start();
        }
    }
```

this good work.

but this all occur exception  showing dialog.

I want when occur only `fail to connect to camera service' exception , showing dialog.

in other word, if my device not connect camera, showing dialog . (not app stop message).

Answer (score 0):

You can put open camera functionality in try catch block and on catching exception show alert you want to show.

Catching exception in open camera will result into camera related exception will not pass to Uncaught exception class and "oops app crash" alert will not gone show.

```
  try {
            myCamera = Camera.open();

       } catch (Exception e) {

        //Here you catch:  Failed to connect to camera service and display alert
        }
```

Comment: thanks, but, I don't understand. you advice catching camera exception ?

Comment: You should in this case always catch the Exception you know about first. The UngoughtExceptionHandler is more like a second safety net which is there to catch Exceptions you might have forgotten.

Comment: Can you simply explain that?

Comment: if you look into Android Developers code they have also cached exception in open camera https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html

Comment: I know open camera, but..  open camera +  uncaughtException

Comment: sorry I'm android beginner